# how to define path of the report that is in a folder in project?

Tags: c#, report, reportviewer

I am working with report viewer.
I have a folder in my project named Reports,in there I have a Report2.rdlc.
When setting my path,I tried

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/Report2.rdlc";
```

when I am setting my images in a xaml,path like this works fine.But with my report,it is looking in some other places.Something like c:/reports,or project/bin/debug/reports..
I have a thing that is working,when I add a report directly to the project:

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "../../Report.rdlc";
```

but what if I wanna have reports in a separate folder?How to access it?
Also,if it is already looking in the bin folder,is it a common practise to create there a folder,and create reports there? Maybe that is a good solution when you copy your app to the clients desktops?Then you just copy the bin folder,nothing else.